# Error with sharepoint client object model

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-clientobject

I got the following error while running SharePoint ClientObject Model. I went through my code and checked if I missed any thing to load, but didn't see.

"Process is Terminated: The property or field has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested."

I am not sure what I am missing after searching about this for a couple of hour.

The following is my code. Hope any one can help.

```
    public static void UpdatePackageStatus(string Teamsite, string Libname, string Packagename, string User, string Password, string Domain, string PackageStatus, string DeploymentSucceeded, string query)
        {
            using(clientOM.ClientContext Ctx = new clientOM.ClientContext(Teamsite))
            {

                Ctx.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(User, Password, Domain);
                clientOM.Web Web = Ctx.Web;
                Ctx.Load(Web);
                Ctx.ExecuteQuery();

                clientOM.List list = Web.Lists.GetByTitle(Libname);
                Ctx.Load(list);
                Ctx.ExecuteQuery();


                clientOM.CamlQuery CamlQuery = new clientOM.CamlQuery();
                CamlQuery.ViewXml = query;

                clientOM.ListItemCollection Items = list.GetItems(CamlQuery);
                Ctx.Load(Items);
                Ctx.ExecuteQuery();

                if(Items.Count > 0)
                {
                    clientOM.ListItem Item = Items.GetById(Items[0].Id);;
                    Ctx.Load(Item);
                    Ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                    if(Item.DisplayName == Packagename)
                    {
                    Item[PackageStatus] = DeploymentSucceeded; 
                    Item.Update(); 
                    Ctx.ExecuteQuery(); 
                    }
                }   
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

All used fields like DisplayName, Id and PackageStatus should be specified manually. You can use CAML query and write something like this:

```
string queryText = @"<View>
    <Query>
        <Where>
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name='{0}'/>
            <Value Type='Text'>{1}</Value>
        </Eq>
        </Where>
    </Query>
    </View>";
CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
query.ViewXml = string.Format(queryText, 'DisplayName', Packagename); //FieldRef = internal field name
ListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(query);
Ctx.Load(listItems, items => items.Include(item => item[PackageStatus]);
Ctx.ExecuteQuery();
if (listItems.Count > 0)
{
    listItems[0][PackageStatus] = DeploymentSucceeded;
    Item.Update(); 
    Ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Comment: Yes, that should work as well. I am writing this code in powershell, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I see a fix.

Instead of using Item.DisplayName, I can use File object. It works when I use File and instantiating it by load(File) like other  property.

```
    clientOM.File file = Item.File;
    Ctx.Load(file);
    Ctx.ExecuteQuery();

    if(file.Name == Packagename)
    {
    Item[PackageStatus] = DeploymentSucceeded; 
    Item.Update(); 
    Ctx.ExecuteQuery(); 
    }
```